# Need help trying to scrape from a object

Tags: javascript, php, dom

So I've started out in the world of scraping so far so good until I've hit a huge hurdle in my quest.

So I'm not sure how possible it is but I'm trying to scrape a bit of text marked as "THISTEXT" from this piece of code.

```
<div id="mainclass">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="400" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.websiteexample.com/channel=THISTEXT" bgcolor="#d7d7d7">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.websiteexample.com/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.websiteexample.com&channel=THISTEXT&auto_play=false&start_volume=100" />
</object>
```

So far I've managed to scrape down the ID but this is where I've hit a wall. Can anybody help me would be much appreciated!

My current code can be found here

```
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) 
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    if(!$doc) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);
    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }
    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}
$finalcontent = getElementByIdAsString('http://examplewebsite.com', 'mainclass');
print_r ($finalcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your example and added some methods to extract the info - it is not pretty but it gives you the info you need.

```
$html = ' 
<div id="mainclass">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="400" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.websiteexample.com/channel=THISTEXT" bgcolor="#d7d7d7">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.websiteexample.com/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.websiteexample.com&channel=THISTEXT&auto_play=false&start_volume=100" />
</object>';

function getElementByIdAsString($html, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html); // changed this from loadHTMLFile() 

    if(!$doc) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);
    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    // get all object tags
    $objects = $element->getElementsByTagName('object'); // return node list

    // take the the value of the data attribute from the first object tag
    $data = $objects->item(0)->getAttributeNode('data')->value;

    // cut away the unnecessary parts and return the info
    return substr($data, strpos($data, '=')+1);

}

// call it:
$finalcontent = getElementByIdAsString($html, 'mainclass');

print_r ($finalcontent);
```

In this example I am using a html string, instead of a file like you. Please consider this when implementing.

Sincerly

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping it means alot! So I'm trying to implement this however I've changed the $html to 'http://www.url.com' and its caused the page to error and go white. Any ideas?

Comment: Even tried reverting it back to $url and then placing my url in the bottom $finalcontent area. No luck.

Comment: Hi, I changed the method `loadHTMLFile()` to `loadHTML()`, maybe this is the problem.